# Determine if the form $x_1^2 + x_2^2 -15(x_3^2+x_4^2)$ is isotropic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, p-adic-number-theory

I'm trying to show whether the form $x_1^2 + x_2^2 -15(x_3^2+x_4^2)$ is isotropic over $\mathbb{Q}$. I tried to apply the strong Hasse principle, but I don't get how to show isotropicity over $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Comment: For $p\nmid 6$ it follows from Hensel lemma and that the reduction $\bmod p$ is isotropic. For $p=\infty$ it is obvious, so it remains to check $p=2,3$. Won't it be anisotropic at $p=3$?

Comment: if $ 3 |   r^2 + s^2 $   in integers, then both $3|r$ and $3|s.$  Start  with $r=x_1  and $s=x_2$   in your form